# UTF-8 character count is not OK in C

Tags: c, utf-8

I want to count the given string count(UTF-8) and I can able to get if the input format given in chines or greek or other UTF-8 string.

**Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define VAL_E0 0xE0
#define VAL_C0 0xC0
int UILexerCheckIsMultiByte(char *pchText , int nLength)
{
  unsigned int nLen = nLength;
  printf ("%s:%d pchText:%s nLen: %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, pchText, nLen);
  char *pchPtr = pchText;

  int tmpVal = VAL_E0;
  int nVal_C0 = VAL_C0;
  int nByteCnt = 2;
  int bIsfound = false;

  while (nLen)
  {
    if ((pchText[nLen-1] & VAL_C0) == VAL_C0)
    {
      do
      {
        if ((pchText[nLen-1] & tmpVal) == nVal_C0)
        {
          bIsfound = true;
          break;
        }

        nByteCnt++;
        tmpVal = tmpVal >> 1 | 0x80;
        nVal_C0= nVal_C0>> 1 | 0x80;
      }while(tmpVal != 0xFF);

      if (bIsfound)
        break;
    }
    nLen--;
  }
  return nByteCnt;
}

int main()
{

 if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8") == NULL) {
    abort();
    }
  char pchBuf[80] = ""; 
  printf("\n Enter the character upto 20 in any form \n");
  scanf("%[^\n]s",pchBuf);
  int nLength=0;
  int nMaxLen=20;
  int nCharCnt = 0;

  do
  {
    if (pchBuf[nLength]& 0x80)
    {
      int nByteCnt=0;
      nByteCnt = UILexerCheckIsMultiByte(pchBuf, nMaxLen);
      nLength += nByteCnt;
      nCharCnt++;
    }
    else
    {
      nCharCnt++;
      nLength++;
    }
  }
  //while(nLength<nMaxLen);
  while(pchBuf[nLength] != '\0');
  printf ("CharCnt: %d \n", nCharCnt);
  return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output:**

> -> ./a.out
>
> ```
>  Enter the character upto 20 in any form
> a擇擇cd
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:a擇擇cd nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:a擇擇cd nLen: 20
> CharCnt: 5
>
> -> ./a.out
>
>      Enter the character upto 20 in any form
>     中国话 不用彁 字。
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:中国话 不用彁 字。 nLen: 20
>     CharCnt: 10
>
>     -> ./a.out
>
>      Enter the character upto 20 in any form
>     Янего
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:Янего nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:Янего nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:Янего nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:Янего nLen: 20
>     UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:Янего nLen: 20
>     CharCnt: 5
> ```

when I use mixed UTF-8 characters, the count is not ok.

> -> ./a.out
>
> ```
>  Enter the character upto 20 in any form
> 用彁 Ĉĉ                                                <==Chinese + roman
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:用彁 Ĉĉ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:用彁 Ĉĉ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:用彁 Ĉĉ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:用彁 Ĉĉ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:用彁 Ĉĉ nLen: 20
> CharCnt: 6
>
>
> -> ./a.out
>
>  Enter the character upto 20 in any form
> 彁用 Αυ                                                 <==Chinese + Greek
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:彁用 Αυ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:彁用 Αυ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:彁用 Αυ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:彁用 Αυ nLen: 20
> UILexerCheckIsMultiByte:11 pchText:彁用 Αυ nLen: 20
> CharCnt: 6
> ```

What modifications Do i need to do to get the correct characters count ?

Comment: Although there's some effort to make this C/C++ (like including **both** `iostream` and `stdio.h`) -- such a "combined" language doesn't exist. So please decide for one. As this looks a lot more like C, I suggest removing the `iostream` and `using namespace std`, as well as the C++ tag.

Comment: Why not use `wchar_t` or `wstring` and [wcout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/wcout/)/[wcin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/wcin/)?

Comment: UTF-8 encoding is for storage and transmission (including console output) but not for in-memory processing. Convert it to Unicode (16/32 bit) and count the characters.

Comment: Removed the [C] tag for you, since this won't compile as C. What did you find is happening when you ran this using your debugger?

Comment: @FelixPalmen thank you. I changed

Comment: Count just the chars that are `<= 127` and > 0xc1`. This count is exactly the number of unicode points. Note: not the number of "glyph", but only the font could get it, and it includes invisible characters.

Comment: Yes, it depends on what you mean by "character". What is this "length" that you need for anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is in UILexerCheckIsMultiByte. To decode utf8 streams you need to look
at the first (highest) 2 bits of each byte. 
if they are "01" it is a 8-bit character code,
if they are "11" it is the first byte of a multi-byte-sequence,
if they are "10" it is one byte inside a multi-byte-sequence.

your first binary compare is correct:
(ch & 0xC0)  == 0xC0  - this will mask the first two bit and will check for the pattern "11xxxxxx" (x means don't care)

but your next compare is wrong. in the first run you check for:
(ch & 0xE0) == 0xC0 - this will mask the first three bit and will check for the pattern "11xxxxx" but you should check for "10xxxxxx".

so maybe you take look at the following code:
there a two versions of strlen and one function to count number of bytes of a multi-byte sequence.

```
 /* gcc -Wall -o strlen strlen.c */                       
 #include "stdio.h"                                                       

 int utf8charsize(char *s)                            
 {                                            
     int cnt=0;                                   
     if( *s ) {                                   
        cnt++;                                    
        if( (*s & 0xc0) == 0x0c0 ) { /* binary is 11xxxxxx */             
            while( (s[cnt] & 0xc0) == 0x80  ) /* binary code is 10xxxxxx */   
            cnt++;                                
        }                                     
     }                                        
     printf("-- %d\n", cnt );                             
     return cnt;                                      
 }                                            


 int utf8strlen(char *s)                                  
 {                                            
     int cnt=0;                                   
     int clen;                                    
     while(*s) {                                      
        clen=utf8charsize(s);                             
        cnt++;                                    
        s+=clen;                                  
     }                                        
     return cnt;                                      
 }                                            

 int utf8strlen2(char *s)                             
 {                                            
     int cnt=0;                                   
     while(*s) {                                      
        cnt++;                                    
        if( (*s++ & 0xc0) == 0x0c0 ) { /* binary is 11xxxxxx */           
            while( (*s & 0xc0) == 0x80  ) /* binary code is 10xxxxxx */       
            s++;                                  
        }                                     
     }                                        
     return cnt;                                      
 }                                            

 int main(int argc, char **argv)                              
 {                                            
     if( argc > 1 )                               
        printf("%d %d\n", utf8strlen(argv[1]), utf8strlen2(argv[1]));         
     return 0;                                            
     }
```